# Spring bean depending on multiple profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean, spring-profiles

I have to create a bean depending of whether one of 2 possible profiles is active, or a different bean if none of that profiles is active. I have the following:

```
    @Profile("!A & !B")
    @Bean(name = "myBean")
    @Autowired
    public Object myBean() {
        ...
    }

    @Profile({"A", "B"})
    @Bean(name = "myBean")
    @Autowired
    public Object myBean() {
        ...
    }
```

This code is working only if no profile A or B is active. To make it work when either A or B are active, I have to switch the order of the bean declaration.

I've tried declaring the beans in different files and it seems t obe working, but I do not understand why this not.

Also I don't understand why `"!A & !B"` notation seems to be working but  `"A | B"` doest not work so I have to use `{"A", "B"}` in that case.

Could you explain why having them in the same files only works for the first bean declared and the notations concern?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can simply test your profile expression with `org.springframework.core.env.Profiles`. For example:

```java
Set<String> activeProfiles = new HashSet<>();
activeProfiles.add("A");
activeProfiles.add("B");

System.out.println(Profiles.of("!A & !B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); //false
System.out.println(Profiles.of("A", "B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); // true
```

Now to your code

1.

> This code is working only if no profile A or B is active

```java
Set<String> activeProfiles = Collections.emptySet();

System.out.println(Profiles.of("!A & !B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); // true
System.out.println(Profiles.of("A", "B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); // false
```

So the first bean is active.

2.

> To make it work when either A or B are active, I have to switch the order of the bean declaration

no, you don't need to switch anything:

```java
Set<String> activeProfiles = new HashSet<>();
activeProfiles.add("A");

System.out.println(Profiles.of("!A & !B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); //false
System.out.println(Profiles.of("A", "B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); // true
```

So the second bean will always be active.

3.

`"A | B"` also works without any problem similarly to `"A", "B"`:

```java
Set<String> activeProfiles = new HashSet<>();
activeProfiles.add("A");

System.out.println(Profiles.of("A | B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); // true
System.out.println(Profiles.of("A", "B").matches(activeProfiles::contains)); // true
```